# How to get a job at Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am trying to get a job as a Stack Exchange system administrator and programmer. Where should I go to sign up for the job?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [work here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) link in the footer of *all* Q&A sites.

Send your application through that page, go through the interview process and if you pass all interviews, you will get hired.

Comment: Just to note, we don't usually hire [13 year olds](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/what-to-do-if-your-threaten-be-your-older-sister). Nor teenagers in general. There are laws, you know...

Answer (score 8):

As [Oded mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274556/245360), there is a list of [open positions](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here), however, the best way to get a job there is getting in the picture.

Do your best to contribute to the community you are finding a job in, like Stack Overflow for programmers. If you have a lot of experience there, run for moderator. Some moderators have been asked to promote to a job at Stack Overflow Inc.

If you don't end up as a moderator, at least your profile has a lot of information you acquired to show your competence in the field, which will give you a job more likely.